# Use regex in expr in Mongodb aggragtion pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have Country Table

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("627cd43f48aea72fdc0d88e0"),
            "county" : "india"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("627cd43f48aea72fdc0d88e1"),
            "county" : "china"
    }
```

And City Table

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("627cd43f48aea72fdc0d88e0"),
            "county_name" : "India"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("627cd43f48aea72fdc0d88e1"),
            "county_name" : "China"
    }
```

In Country Table Country name is in lower letter and In City Table Country Name is in Upper Letter. So Now how can use like condition to join both collection with matching same name.
Ex. Get Data of india Like India

```js
    db.getCollection('countryTable').aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "cityTable",
                let: { county: "$county" },
                pipeline: [{
                    $match: {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$regexMatch": {
                                "input": "$county_name",
                                "regex": "$$county",
                                "options": "i"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }],
                as: "citydetails"
            }
        },
        { $unwind: "$citydetails" }
    ])
```

Comment: [Your query works](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D21CyOIBice).

Comment: @YongShun I am getting on My Mongo Shell. InvalidPipelineOperator $regexMatch

Comment: What's client and server version

Comment: What client are you using, mongo shell or any other.

Comment: @Gibbs MongoDB 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoDB v4.0, you can do the `$match` in subpipeline with `$toLower`

```js
db.countryTable.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "cityTable",
      let: {
        county: "$county"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "$expr": {
              $eq: [
                {
                  "$toLower": "$$county"
                },
                {
                  "$toLower": "$county_name"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "citydetails"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$citydetails"
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kEy4z8qYSWu) for your reference.

Comment: convert this to lower will working for 20 out of 29. need to use regex for that. So How to use regex?

Comment: @skodretsolutions If you check the [official doc of $regexMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/), you will see it's only available starting from v4.2+. You may consider upgrading your MongoDB version.